# Using the jQuery Validate plugin, how can I wrap the error message string in a span

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Does anyone know how to wrap the inner error string in a span? I'm using the jQuery Validate plugin for my form and getting the default error message displaying in label tags, which is fine for now. Example:

```
<label class="error" for="email">This field is required</label>
```

I would like to wrap the error text string in a span so that I can get the pixel width of that text string. Would like it to look like this:

```
<label class="error" for="email"><span class="youreAwesome">This field is required</span></label>
```

Reasoning: I'm trying to get the pixel width of the text string and apply that width to the parent container. I have varying error message lengths (some short and some long) with a bright red background on each. I do not want to set a fixed width for all because a short error message with a super long red background would look weird in my design (and vica versa).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How can you get the pixel width of the `span` but not the `label`?  In other words, `label` and `span` are both inline elements so if you can get the width of the `span`, you would also be able to get the width of the `label`.  My point is that I don't see how altering the markup in this fashion is going to make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the `errorElement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorelement) to wrap each item in a `span`.

Then use [the `wrapper` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#wrapper) to enclose each `span` within a `label`

```
$('#myform').validate({
    errorElement: 'span',
    wrapper: 'label'
    ....
```

Will give you...

```
<label><span class="error">This is Required</span></label>
```

For CSS & jQuery targeting, you don't need a special `class` as you can select like this...

```
label > span
```

OR more specifically...

```
label > span.error
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/s89ommhx/**

Comment: Is there an easy way to do this through out my application once. I have tons of places I call $('#myform').validate()?

Comment: @AmeteBlessed, look at the `.setDefaults()` method in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wrapInner` .

```
$('.error').wrapInner( "<span class='youreAwesome'></span>");
```

As per op comment :

```
$(".selector").validate({
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
  $('.error').wrapInner( "<span class='youreAwesome'></span>"); 
   }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/8jc1wuq2/)

Comment: That's true, but I would like this to fire during the actual validation process. Do you know how I can add this to the validate function?

Answer (score -1):

you can define your error message like:

```
var validator = form.validate({
  rules: {
    username: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3
    }
  },
  messages: {
    username: {
      required: '<span> required </span>',
      minlength: ''
    }
  },
```

Comment: Never thought of this. I'm digging the simplistic approach, but there are a bunch of error messages I would have to add this to. Is there any other way I can add a function to validate() that will do this during the validation process?